# Hi im and able to send notifications via email from excel using VBA now im trying to get the information that was updated into th

Tags: vba

Hi im and able to send notifications via email from excel using VBA now im trying to get the information that was updated into the body of the email(objMessage.HTMLBody = ) in my case it will always be Sheet1 (A5:K5) any advise?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This will show you how to convert a Range to HTML (for the body of an Email)

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm